# route url changed when javascript call occurs in nt-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My HTML is in ng-template tag and it loaded when i click button using Routing, but when jquery call occurs in the html it disappers and url also changed.

Comment: <p><a href = "#viewSearch">View Search</a></p>
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "Search.htm">
<input type="button" id="clickme"></div><span id="spn">Hi</span>
</script>
<script>
$("#clickme").click(function(){
$("#spn").hide();
});
</script>

Comment: Need to provide [mcve] Nobody can help without seeing your code in order to be able to reproduce problem